# passportjs mongoose model with required field

Tags: mongoose, model, passport.js, required

Does anyone know why we cannot define a mongoose model that is used by passport with required field on username, passport, phone, email and name? If I do not write required or use required:false it works fine.

for example this model gives error if you use it in passportjs

```
    var userSchema=new Schema({
  username:{trype:String},  //As I use directly userSchema in passportJs I cannot use required:true for the files. I do not know hy yet anyhow.
  password:{trype:String},
  name:{trype:String,required:true}
});
```

Error:

```
throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
^
```

TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `name.required`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (XX\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:644:11)

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo. It should be ‘type’ and not ‘trype’

Comment: OMG many thx I did not realize it!